# keyword - FFL: Where vs. Let

Tags: where-clause, let, anura, ffl

I was trying to understand the following code:

```
    def() ->commands
        if(deferred_passive_abilities != [],
           let [{ability: class passive_ability, creature: class creature}] items = [];
           let found = false;
           map(deferred_passive_abilities,
             if(cmd = null, add(items, [value]), [cmd, set(found, true)])
             where cmd = value.ability.static_effect(me, value.creature));

           if(found,
              set(deferred_passive_abilities, items);
              evaluate_deferred_passive_abilities(),
              set(deferred_passive_abilities, []))
        )
```

Haskell appears to have both `let` and `where`, but I didn't learn much by a superficial reading of their haskell docs. They also have a `let...in`, which I didn't understand but it would be good to know if FFL has that.

So, what is the significance of using `let` versus `where`? Was it necessary to use `let` here? (Also, possibly another question: why does it need those semicolons?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `let` introduces a variable that can be modified. Note how `found` and `items` are modified. By contrast, `where` always introduces immutable symbols.

Semi-colons are used in FFL to create a **command pipeline**. Normally in FFL, an entire formula is **evaluated**, resulting in a command or list of commands, and then the commands are **executed**.

When a semi-colon is present, everything before the semi-colon is treated as an entirely separate formula to everything after the semi-colon. The first formula is **evaluated** and **executed** and then the second formula is evaluated and executed.

Semi-colons effectively allow a much more procedural programming style in FFL, without semi-colons it is a purely functional language.

Answer (score 2):

Never knew of `let` in FFL before this, must be very rare.

Regardless of the insights, the semicolon has to be absolutely necessary, in order to force execution before using the bound variable. In other words, until used the semicolon, the variable does not *exist*. Does not have a bound value.

This is a big difference to `where`, which doesn't need of semicolons.

Given the semicolon is not a construction for complete beginners, I could somewhat recommend beginners about variables to stick in `where` until understanding the trickery of the semicolons.

Comment: You can check [the main question about the semicolon relationship to the comma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50457675/1737973) as the reason to consider the semicolon an element somewhat less straightforward than it could seem at first sight.