# Understanding the evaluation and execution order with semicolon syntax

Tags: syntax, purely-functional, anura, ffl

I already learned a little bit about FFL semicolons from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50457299/keyword-ffl-where-vs-let). However, it is still not clear what order of evaluation or execution they enforce. So here is a more concrete example:

```
 [ expr_a, expr_b ; expr_c, expr_d ; expr_e, expr_f ]
```

What should be the order of execution for the above code? In my head, it should be:

1. evaluate a & b
2. execute a, execute b
3. evaluate c & d
4. execute c, execute d
5. evaluate e & f
6. execute e, execute f

Now let's imagine that `expr_b = add(test_list, ['b saw ' + str(test_list)])` and similar for all the other expressions. Then what would be the final contents of `test_list`?

In my head, it should be:

> a saw []
>
> b saw []
>
> c saw [a saw [], b saw []]
>
> d saw [a saw [], b saw []]
>
> e saw [a saw [], b saw [], c saw [a saw [], b saw []], d saw [a saw [], b saw []]]
>
> f saw [a saw [], b saw [], c saw [a saw [], b saw []], d saw [a saw [], b saw []]]

Please explain why that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, you probably don't want to write code exactly like this. Generally, semi-colons have very low precedence, but a list literal isn't an operator, and the code will be seen like this:

`[a, (b; c), (d; e), f]`

This means that you are starting off four command pipelines in parallel (though two of them only have a single member). It will evaluate `a`, `b`, `d`, `f`. Then it will execute the results of `a`, then the results of `b`. Executing `b` will trigger the next step in the command pipeline, so it will evaluate and execute `c`. Then it will execute `d`, then evaluate and execute `e`, finally it will execute `f`.

So:

```
a saw []
b saw []
c saw [a saw [], b saw []]
d saw []
e saw [a saw [], b saw [], c saw [a saw [], b saw []], d saw []]
f saw []
```